# making the Python function default value be evaluated each time the function is called

Tags: python, function

How can I make a Python function default value be evaluated each time the function is called?
Take this dummy code:

```
b=0
def a():
    global b
    return b

def c(d=a()):
    return d
```

What I would expect as output:

```
>>> c()
0
>>> b=1
>>> a()
1
>>> c()
1
```

What I actually get:

```
>>> c()
0
>>> b=1
>>> a()
1
>>> c()
0
```

Comment: That is not actually possible, and the best way to solve it depends highly on your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One more solution, in closer resemblance to your original answer.

```
b = 0
def a():
    return b

def c(d=a):    # When it's a parameter, the call will be evaluated and its return 
               # value will be used. Instead, just use the function name, because
    return d() # within the scope of the function, the call will be evaluated every time.
```

When a function name is paired with the parentheses and its parameters, like `f(x)`, it is assumed your intention is to call it at that time

Answer (score 1):

d=a() is evaluated at <s>start of program</s> when function c is defined  (ie a() gets called while it returns 0 ...)

```
def c(d=None):
    if d == None: d=a()
    return d
```

will cause it to be evaluated at the time you want

Comment: Not exactly "_at start of program_", but "_when the function is defined_". It may be nested for example, so the function will be defined when the surrounding function will be called. But the basic idea (to use `None` as default argument and then check if it has been changed) is okay.

Comment: yeah ... at first i had compile time ... but was drawing a blank on how to say "when function is defined"

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is, as you probably already know, that the `d=a()` (default argument assignement) is evaluated when the function is defined.

To change that, it is pretty common to use eg. `None` as default argument and evaluate it in the body of the function:

```
b=0
def a():
    global b
    return b

def c(d=None):
    if d is None:
        d = a()
    return d
```

Comment: @JoranBeasley: Thanks ;) See comment to your answer (it may be too strict for OP's needs however).

Answer (score 1):

I'll give a slight variation on the above:

```
b = 0

def a():
    # unless you are writing changes to b, you do not have to make it a global
    return b

def c(d=None, get_d=a):
    if d is None:
        d = get_d()
    return d
```